# How to resolve symbolic links in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, symlink

Given an absolute or relative path (in a Unix-like system), I would like to determine the full path of the target after resolving any intermediate symlinks. Bonus points for also resolving ~username notation at the same time.

If the target is a directory, it might be possible to chdir() into the directory and then call getcwd(), but I really want to do this from a shell script rather than writing a C helper. Unfortunately, shells have a tendency to try to hide the existence of symlinks from the user (this is bash on OS X):

```
$ ls -ld foo bar
drwxr-xr-x   2 greg  greg  68 Aug 11 22:36 bar
lrwxr-xr-x   1 greg  greg   3 Aug 11 22:36 foo -> bar
$ cd foo
$ pwd
/Users/greg/tmp/foo
$
```

What I want is a function resolve() such that when executed from the tmp directory in the above example, resolve("foo") == "/Users/greg/tmp/bar".

Answer (score 102, accepted):

According to the standards, `pwd -P` should return the path with symlinks resolved.

C function `char *getcwd(char *buf, size_t size)` from `unistd.h` should have the same behaviour.

[getcwd](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getcwd.html)
[pwd](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/pwd.html)

Comment: This just works for (the current) directory? If the target is a file, it will not give anything...

Comment: Doesn't work if the link is broken as you cannot make it your current path

Comment: To summarize with the benefit of hindsight: This answer works only in very limited circumstances, namely if the symlink of interest is to a _directory_ that actually _exists_; plus, you must `cd` to it first, before calling `pwd -P`.
In other words: it won't allow you to resolve (see the target of) symlinks _to files_ or of _broken_ symlinks, and for resolving existing-directory symlinks you have to do additional work (restore the previous working dir or localize the `cd` and `pwd -P` calls in a subshell).

Comment: to bad I look for a way to resolve a file and not a directory.

Comment: As others have pointed out, this doesn't really answer the question. @pixelbeat's answer below does.

Comment: @dala You could use [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76228/156470) in your script to filter any „trailing“ filename (for ease of mind and paste :)

Comment: This works if the input is a directory, or a file in a symlinked directory and you have a normal file after it. `[-d "$1"] && echo $(cd $1; pwd -P) || echo $(cd $(dirname $1); pwd -P)/$(basename $1) | sed 's=//=/=g'` it does not work if the file itself is a symlink.

Answer (score 474):

```
readlink -f "$path"
```

<sup>Editor's note: The above works with *GNU* `readlink` and *FreeBSD/PC-BSD/OpenBSD* `readlink`, but *not* on OS X as of 10.11.

*GNU* `readlink` offers additional, related options, such as `-m` for resolving a symlink whether or not the ultimate target exists.</sup>

Note since GNU coreutils 8.15 (2012-01-06), there is a **realpath** program available that is less obtuse and more flexible than the above. It's also compatible with the FreeBSD util of the same name. It also includes functionality to generate a relative path between two files.

```
realpath $path
```

---

[Admin addition below from comment by [halloleo](/users/65889/halloleo) —[danorton]](/users/65889/danorton)

For Mac OS X (through at least 10.11.x), use `readlink` without the `-f` option:

```
readlink $path
```

<sup>Editor's note: This will not resolve symlinks *recursively* and thus won't report the *ultimate* target; e.g., given symlink `a` that points to `b`, which in turn points to `c`, this will only report `b` (and won't ensure that it is output as an *absolute path*).

Use the following `perl` command on OS X to fill the gap of the missing `readlink -f` functionality:

`perl -MCwd -le 'print Cwd::abs_path(shift)' "$path"`</sup>

Comment: This doesn't work in Mac OS X - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055671/how-can-i-get-the-behavior-of-gnus-readlink-f-on-a-mac

Comment: shame about OS X incompatibility, otherwise nice +1

Comment: On OS X you can install coreutils with homebrew. It installs it as "grealpath".

Comment: `readlink` works on OSX, but needs another syntax: `readlink $path` *without* the `-f`.

Comment: readlink fails to de-reference multiple layers of symlink though, it just derefs one layer at a time

Comment: Both `readlink -f` and `realpath` in coreutils, do dereference all "layers" of symlinks

Comment: Even the most simple shells support subshells, and cd'ing in those subshells doesn't affect the outside. So if your link to resolve is a directory, you can do something along the lines of `( CDPATH="" cd -P -- "$path" ; pwd -P )`

Comment: are these two program built-in of Sun Solaris?, I can't find them on my host. my host info is: SunOS xxx 5.10 Generic_138888-08 sun4v sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise-T5120

Comment: No solaris doesn't have these. You would need to build GNU coreutils for your system.

Comment: I don't have `realpath` on Centos 6 with GNU coreutils 8.4.31. I've come across several others on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) that have a GNU coreutils packaged *without* `realpath`. So it seems to be dependent on more than just version.

Comment: Note by design the coreutils realpath is mostly compatible with the separate realpath package/program on debian/ubuntu. The separate realpath maintainer would like to switch to the GNU coreutils version too. This is tracked at https://bugs.debian.org/730779

Comment: Hey hey, I have one caveat.  If you use ls -F to read your symlink into a variable, you will get an @ in your symlink name.  This causes readlink to fail silently.  It caused much confusion for me.

Comment: Mind if I bash Perl? Don't you love its clear semantics? LOL.

Comment: readlink -f works for me on cygwin and returns a unix-style path.

Comment: This works for me (tested with Sierra) :

`while [ -L "${path}" ]; do path=$(readlink "${path}"); done`

Comment: @Kuro  good idea, but that only tests the last element of the path (basename). It doesn't catch symlinks within the earlier directories of the path.

Answer (score 28):

"pwd -P" seems to work if you just want the directory, but if for some reason you want the name of the actual executable I don't think that helps. Here's my solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

# get the absolute path of the executable
SELF_PATH=$(cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "$0")" && pwd -P) && SELF_PATH=$SELF_PATH/$(basename -- "$0")

# resolve symlinks
while [[ -h $SELF_PATH ]]; do
    # 1) cd to directory of the symlink
    # 2) cd to the directory of where the symlink points
    # 3) get the pwd
    # 4) append the basename
    DIR=$(dirname -- "$SELF_PATH")
    SYM=$(readlink "$SELF_PATH")
    SELF_PATH=$(cd "$DIR" && cd "$(dirname -- "$SYM")" && pwd)/$(basename -- "$SYM")
done
```

Answer (score 23):

One of my favorites is `realpath foo`

```
realpath - return the canonicalized absolute pathname

realpath  expands  all  symbolic  links  and resolves references to '/./', '/../' and extra '/' characters in the null terminated string named by path and
       stores the canonicalized absolute pathname in the buffer of size PATH_MAX named by resolved_path.  The resulting path will have no symbolic link, '/./' or
       '/../' components.
```

Comment: On Debian (etch and later) this command is available in the realpath package.

Comment: realpath is now (Jan 2012) part of coreutils and backwards compatible with the debian and BSD variant

Comment: I don't have `realpath` on Centos 6 with GNU coreutils 8.4.31. I've come across several others on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) that have a GNU coreutils packaged *without* `realpath`. So it seems to be dependent on more than just version.

Comment: I prefer `realpath` over `readlink` because it offers option flags such as `--relative-to`

Answer (score 10):

```
readlink -e [filepath]
```

seems to be exactly what you're asking for 
- it accepts an arbirary path, resolves all symlinks, and returns the "real" path
- and it's "standard *nix" that likely all systems already have

Comment: Just got bitten by it. It doesn't work on Mac and I'm searching for replacement.

Answer (score 6):

Another way:

```
# Gets the real path of a link, following all links
myreadlink() { [ ! -h "$1" ] && echo "$1" || (local link="$(expr "$(command ls -ld -- "$1")" : '.*-> \(.*\)$')"; cd $(dirname $1); myreadlink "$link" | sed "s|^\([^/].*\)\$|$(dirname $1)/\1|"); }

# Returns the absolute path to a command, maybe in $PATH (which) or not. If not found, returns the same
whereis() { echo $1 | sed "s|^\([^/].*/.*\)|$(pwd)/\1|;s|^\([^/]*\)$|$(which -- $1)|;s|^$|$1|"; } 

# Returns the realpath of a called command.
whereis_realpath() { local SCRIPT_PATH=$(whereis $1); myreadlink ${SCRIPT_PATH} | sed "s|^\([^/].*\)\$|$(dirname ${SCRIPT_PATH})/\1|"; }
```

Comment: I need cd  in myreadlink(), because it is a recursive function, going to each directory until it finds a link. If it finds a link, returns the realpath, and then sed would replace the path.

Answer (score 5):

Putting some of the given solutions together, knowing that readlink is available on most systems, but needs different arguments, this works well for me on OSX and Debian. I'm not sure about BSD systems. Maybe the condition needs to be `[[ $OSTYPE != darwin* ]]` to exclude `-f` from OSX only.

```
#!/bin/bash
MY_DIR=$( cd $(dirname $(readlink `[[ $OSTYPE == linux* ]] && echo "-f"` $0)) ; pwd -P)
echo "$MY_DIR"
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's how one can get the actual path to the file in MacOS/Unix using an inline Perl script:

```
FILE=$(perl -e "use Cwd qw(abs_path); print abs_path('$0')")
```

Similarly, to get the directory of a symlinked file:

```
DIR=$(perl -e "use Cwd qw(abs_path); use File::Basename; print dirname(abs_path('$0'))")
```

Answer (score 3):

Common shell scripts often have to find their "home" directory even if they are invoked as a symlink. The script thus have to find their "real" position from just $0.

```
cat `mvn`
```

on my system prints a script containing the following, which should be a good hint at what you need.

```
if [ -z "$M2_HOME" ] ; then
  ## resolve links - $0 may be a link to maven's home
  PRG="$0"

  # need this for relative symlinks
  while [ -h "$PRG" ] ; do
    ls=`ls -ld "$PRG"`
    link=`expr "$ls" : '.*-> \(.*\)$'`
    if expr "$link" : '/.*' > /dev/null; then
      PRG="$link"
    else
      PRG="`dirname "$PRG"`/$link"
    fi
  done

  saveddir=`pwd`

  M2_HOME=`dirname "$PRG"`/..

  # make it fully qualified
  M2_HOME=`cd "$M2_HOME" && pwd`
```

Answer (score 3):

*Update*:

- **As of at least macOS 13 (Ventura), macOS now also supports `readlink -f`** for following a symlink *to its ultimate target* (FreeBSD has had support for much longer), so the need for a *POSIX-compliant* solution has lessened considerably.
- However, **a POSIX-compliant solution - as implemented below - may still be of interest**:

  - If you need to support older macOS versions and other Unix-like platforms where `readlink -f` is not implemented.
  - and/or you need *consistent behavior across platforms*:

    - Notably, `readlink -f` on macOS / FreeBSD is *not* equivalent to the GNU implementation (as found on Linux distros): `-f` on macOS / FreeBSD corresponds to GNU `-e`, which enforces the existence of the ultimate target (GNU's `-f` allows the *last path segment* of the ultimate target to be non-existent).

---

Below is a **fully POSIX-compliant script / function** that is therefore **cross-platform** (works on macOS too, whose `readlink` still doesn't support `-f` as of 10.12 (Sierra)) - it uses only [POSIX shell language features](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#) and only POSIX-compliant utility calls.

It is a **portable implementation of GNU's `readlink -e`** (the stricter version of `readlink -f`).

You can **run the *script* with `sh`** or **source the *function* in `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh`**:

For instance, inside a script you can use it as follows to get the running's script true directory of origin, with symlinks resolved:

```
trueScriptDir=$(dirname -- "$(rreadlink "$0")")
```

---

**`rreadlink` script / function definition:**

<sup>The code was adapted with gratitude from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1116890/45375).

I've also created a `bash`-based stand-alone utility version [here](https://github.com/mklement0/rreadlink), which you can install with

`npm install rreadlink -g`, if you have Node.js installed.</sup>

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# SYNOPSIS
#   rreadlink <fileOrDirPath>
# DESCRIPTION
#   Resolves <fileOrDirPath> to its ultimate target, if it is a symlink, and
#   prints its canonical path. If it is not a symlink, its own canonical path
#   is printed.
#   A broken symlink causes an error that reports the non-existent target.
# LIMITATIONS
#   - Won't work with filenames with embedded newlines or filenames containing 
#     the string ' -> '.
# COMPATIBILITY
#   This is a fully POSIX-compliant implementation of what GNU readlink's
#    -e option does.
# EXAMPLE
#   In a shell script, use the following to get that script's true directory of origin:
#     trueScriptDir=$(dirname -- "$(rreadlink "$0")")
rreadlink() ( # Execute the function in a *subshell* to localize variables and the effect of `cd`.

  target=$1 fname= targetDir= CDPATH=

  # Try to make the execution environment as predictable as possible:
  # All commands below are invoked via `command`, so we must make sure that
  # `command` itself is not redefined as an alias or shell function.
  # (Note that command is too inconsistent across shells, so we don't use it.)
  # `command` is a *builtin* in bash, dash, ksh, zsh, and some platforms do not 
  # even have an external utility version of it (e.g, Ubuntu).
  # `command` bypasses aliases and shell functions and also finds builtins 
  # in bash, dash, and ksh. In zsh, option POSIX_BUILTINS must be turned on for
  # that to happen.
  { \unalias command; \unset -f command; } >/dev/null 2>&1
  [ -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ] && options[POSIX_BUILTINS]=on # make zsh find *builtins* with `command` too.

  while :; do # Resolve potential symlinks until the ultimate target is found.
      [ -L "$target" ] || [ -e "$target" ] || { command printf '%s\n' "ERROR: '$target' does not exist." >&2; return 1; }
      command cd "$(command dirname -- "$target")" # Change to target dir; necessary for correct resolution of target path.
      fname=$(command basename -- "$target") # Extract filename.
      [ "$fname" = '/' ] && fname='' # !! curiously, `basename /` returns '/'
      if [ -L "$fname" ]; then
        # Extract [next] target path, which may be defined
        # *relative* to the symlink's own directory.
        # Note: We parse `ls -l` output to find the symlink target
        #       which is the only POSIX-compliant, albeit somewhat fragile, way.
        target=$(command ls -l "$fname")
        target=${target#* -> }
        continue # Resolve [next] symlink target.
      fi
      break # Ultimate target reached.
  done
  targetDir=$(command pwd -P) # Get canonical dir. path
  # Output the ultimate target's canonical path.
  # Note that we manually resolve paths ending in /. and /.. to make sure we have a normalized path.
  if [ "$fname" = '.' ]; then
    command printf '%s\n' "${targetDir%/}"
  elif  [ "$fname" = '..' ]; then
    # Caveat: something like /var/.. will resolve to /private (assuming /var@ -> /private/var), i.e. the '..' is applied
    # AFTER canonicalization.
    command printf '%s\n' "$(command dirname -- "${targetDir}")"
  else
    command printf '%s\n' "${targetDir%/}/$fname"
  fi
)

rreadlink "$@"
```

---

**A tangent on security:**

[jarno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4414935/jarno), in reference to the function ensuring that builtin `command` is not shadowed by an alias or shell function of the same name, asks in a comment:

> What if `unalias` or `unset` and `[` are set as aliases or shell functions?

The motivation behind `rreadlink` ensuring that `command` has its original meaning is to use it to bypass (benign) *convenience* aliases and functions often used to shadow standard commands in interactive shells, such as redefining `ls` to include favorite options.

I think it's safe to say that unless you're dealing with an untrusted, malicious environment, worrying about `unalias` or `unset` - or, for that matter, `while`, `do`, ... - being redefined is not a concern.

There is *something* that the function must rely on to have its original meaning and behavior - there is no way around that.
That POSIX-like shells allow redefinition of builtins and even language keywords is *inherently* a security risk (and writing paranoid code is hard in general).

To address your concerns specifically:

The function relies on `unalias` and `unset` having their original meaning. Having them redefined as *shell functions* in a manner that alters their behavior would be a problem; redefinition as an *alias* is
not necessarily a concern, because *quoting* (part of) the command name (e.g., `\unalias`) bypasses aliases.

However, quoting is *not* an option for shell *keywords* (`while`, `for`, `if`, `do`, ...) and while shell keywords do take precedence over shell *functions*, in `bash` and `zsh` aliases have the highest precedence, so to guard against shell-keyword redefinitions you must run `unalias` with their names (although in *non-interactive* `bash` shells (such as scripts) aliases are *not* expanded by default - only if `shopt -s expand_aliases` is explicitly called first).

To ensure that `unalias` - as a builtin - has its original meaning, you must use `\unset` on it first, which requires that `unset` have its original meaning:

`unset` is a shell *builtin*, so to ensure that it is invoked as such, you'd have to make sure that it itself is not redefined as a *function*. While you can bypass an alias form with quoting, you cannot bypass a shell-function form - catch 22.

Thus, unless you can rely on `unset` to have its original meaning, from what I can tell, there is no guaranteed way to defend against all malicious redefinitions.

Comment: In my experience, quoting bypasses aliases, not shell functions, unlike you first tell.

Comment: I tested that I can define `[` as an alias in `dash` and `bash` and as a shell function in `bash`.

Comment: I made my point as a separate [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35916983/4414935).

Comment: @jarno: Good points; I've updated my answer; let me know if you think there's still a problem.

Comment: Just a note: I could not define `while` as shell function in either `bash` or `dash`. I can define `while` as an alias in `bash`; thereafter it is recognized as alias (unlike in `dash`). (Tested by GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release, and dash package version 0.5.7)

Comment: @jarno: You _can_ define `while` as a function in `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh` (but not `dash`), but only with `function <name>` syntax: `function while { echo foo; }` works (`while() { echo foo; }` doesn't). However, this wont' shadow the `while` _keyword_, because keywords have higher precedence than functions (the only way to invoke this function is as `\while`). In `bash` and `zsh`, aliases have higher precedence than keywords, so _alias_ redefinitions of keywords do shadow them (but in `bash` by default only in _interactive_ shells, unless `shopt -s expand_aliases` is explicitly called).

Comment: very good but unfortunately unneded work. there are coreutils described in other hints, that is much enough for resolve symlinks, and much more. Currently (2023 year) all OSes has built in readlink with -f flags , pwd -P (for only current directory) and realpath. Of course, this all except os'es from microsoft and apple. those systems needs install additional GNU software, port of coreutils or similar.

Comment: @Znik, please see the top section I've just added to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Is your path a directory, or might it be a file? If it's a directory, it's simple:

```
(cd "$DIR"; pwd -P)
```

However, if it might be a file, then this won't work:

```
DIR=$(cd $(dirname "$FILE"); pwd -P); echo "${DIR}/$(readlink "$FILE")"
```

because the symlink might resolve into a relative or full path.

On scripts I need to find the real path, so that I might reference configuration or other scripts installed together with it, I use this:

```
SOURCE="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
while [ -h "$SOURCE" ]; do # resolve $SOURCE until the file is no longer a symlink
  DIR="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE" )" && pwd )"
  SOURCE="$(readlink "$SOURCE")"
  [[ $SOURCE != /* ]] && SOURCE="$DIR/$SOURCE" # if $SOURCE was a relative symlink, we need to resolve it relative to the path where the symlink file was located
done
```

You could set `SOURCE` to any file path. Basically, for as long as the path is a symlink, it resolves that symlink. The trick is in the last line of the loop. If the resolved symlink is absolute, it will use that as `SOURCE`. However, if it is relative, it will prepend the `DIR` for it, which was resolved into a real location by the simple trick I first described.

Answer (score 3):

In case where pwd can't be used (e.g. calling a scripts from a different location), use realpath (with or without dirname):

```
$(dirname $(realpath $PATH_TO_BE_RESOLVED))
```

Works both when calling through (multiple) symlink(s) or when directly calling the script - from any location.

Answer (score 2):

```
function realpath {
    local r=$1; local t=$(readlink $r)
    while [ $t ]; do
        r=$(cd $(dirname $r) && cd $(dirname $t) && pwd -P)/$(basename $t)
        t=$(readlink $r)
    done
    echo $r
}

#example usage
SCRIPT_PARENT_DIR=$(dirname $(realpath "$0"))/..
```

Comment: This will break with (a) any path containing whitespace or shell metacharacters and (b) broken symlinks (not an issue with if you just want the running script's parent path, assuming (a) doesn't apply).

Comment: If you are concerned with whitespace use quotes.

Comment: Please do - although that won't address (b).

Comment: Please show me an example of b) where this fails. By definition, a broken symlink points to a directory entry that doesn't exist. The point of this script is to resolve symlinks in the other direction. If the symlink were broken you wouldn't be executing the script. This example is intended to demonstrate resolving the currently executing script.

Comment: "intended to demonstrate resolving the currently executing script" - indeed, which is a narrowing of the question's scope you've elected to focus on; that is perfectly fine, as long as you say so. Since you didn't, I stated it in my comment. Please fix the quoting issue, which is a problem irrespective of the scope of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a symlink resolver in Bash that works whether the link is a directory or a non-directory:

```
function readlinks {(
  set -o errexit -o nounset
  declare n=0 limit=1024 link="$1"

  # If it's a directory, just skip all this.
  if cd "$link" 2>/dev/null
  then
    pwd -P
    return 0
  fi

  # Resolve until we are out of links (or recurse too deep).
  while [[ -L $link ]] && [[ $n -lt $limit ]]
  do
    cd "$(dirname -- "$link")"
    n=$((n + 1))
    link="$(readlink -- "${link##*/}")"
  done
  cd "$(dirname -- "$link")"

  if [[ $n -ge $limit ]]
  then
    echo "Recursion limit ($limit) exceeded." >&2
    return 2
  fi

  printf '%s/%s\n' "$(pwd -P)" "${link##*/}"
)}
```

Note that all the `cd` and `set` stuff takes place in a subshell.

Comment: Actually, the { } around the ( ) are unnecessary, since ( ) counts as a "compound command", just like { }. But you still need () after the function name.

Comment: @ChrisCogdon The `{}` around the `()` are not unnecessary if there are no `()` behind the function name. Bash accepts function declarations without `()` because shell does not have parameter lists in declarations and doesn't do calls with `()` so function declarations with `()` don't make a lot of sense.

Comment: This will break if symlink has paths in it, e.g., `../dir1/dir2/file`

Comment: Can you give an example of a setup where it broke? It ultimately prints the physical path (`pwd -P`) so I'm not sure you mean by broken; it won't always be the shortest possible way to print the path.

Answer (score 1):

To work around the Mac incompatibility, I came up with

```
echo `php -r "echo realpath('foo');"`
```

Not great but cross OS

Comment: Python 2.6+ is available on more end-user systems than php, so `python -c "from os import path; print(path.realpath('${SYMLINK_PATH}'));"` would probably make more sense. Still, by the time you need to use Python from a shell script, you should probably just use Python and save yourself the headache of cross platform shell scripting.

Comment: You don't need any more than the sh built-ins readlink, dirname and basename.

Comment: @Dave: `dirname`, `basename`, and `readlink` are external _utilities_, not shell built-ins; `dirname` and `basename` are part of POSIX, `readlink` is not.

Comment: @mklement0 - You are quite right. They are provided by CoreUtils or equivalent. I shouldn't visit SO after 1am. The essence of my comment is that neither PHP nor any other language interpreter beyond that installed in a base system are required. I have used the script I provided on this page on _every_ linux variant since 1997 and MacOS X since 2006 without error. The OP didn't ask for a POSIX solution. Their specific environment was Mac OS X.

Comment: @Dave: Yes, it _is_ possible to do it with stock utilities, but it is also _hard_ to do so (as evidenced by the shortcomings of your script). If OS X were truly the focus, then this answer _is_ perfectly fine - and much simpler -  given that `php` comes with OS X.
However, even though the _body_ of the question mentions OS X, it is not tagged as such, and it's become clear that people on various platforms come here for answers, so it's worth pointing out what's platform-specific / non-POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cd $(dirname $([ -L $0 ] && readlink -f $0 || echo $0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I've run into this many times over the years, and this time around I needed a pure bash portable version that I could use on OSX and linux, I went ahead and wrote one:

The living version lives here:

https://github.com/keen99/shell-functions/tree/master/resolve_path

but for the sake of SO, here's the current version (I feel it's well tested..but I'm open to feedback!)

Might not be difficult to make it work for plain bourne shell (sh), but I didn't try...I like $FUNCNAME too much. :)

```
#!/bin/bash

resolve_path() {
    #I'm bash only, please!
    # usage:  resolve_path <a file or directory> 
    # follows symlinks and relative paths, returns a full real path
    #
    local owd="$PWD"
    #echo "$FUNCNAME for $1" >&2
    local opath="$1"
    local npath=""
    local obase=$(basename "$opath")
    local odir=$(dirname "$opath")
    if [[ -L "$opath" ]]
    then
    #it's a link.
    #file or directory, we want to cd into it's dir
        cd $odir
    #then extract where the link points.
        npath=$(readlink "$obase")
        #have to -L BEFORE we -f, because -f includes -L :(
        if [[ -L $npath ]]
         then
        #the link points to another symlink, so go follow that.
            resolve_path "$npath"
            #and finish out early, we're done.
            return $?
            #done
        elif [[ -f $npath ]]
        #the link points to a file.
         then
            #get the dir for the new file
            nbase=$(basename $npath)
            npath=$(dirname $npath)
            cd "$npath"
            ndir=$(pwd -P)
            retval=0
            #done
        elif [[ -d $npath ]]
         then
        #the link points to a directory.
            cd "$npath"
            ndir=$(pwd -P)
            retval=0
            #done
        else
            echo "$FUNCNAME: ERROR: unknown condition inside link!!" >&2
            echo "opath [[ $opath ]]" >&2
            echo "npath [[ $npath ]]" >&2
            return 1
        fi
    else
        if ! [[ -e "$opath" ]]
         then
            echo "$FUNCNAME: $opath: No such file or directory" >&2
            return 1
            #and break early
        elif [[ -d "$opath" ]]
         then 
            cd "$opath"
            ndir=$(pwd -P)
            retval=0
            #done
        elif [[ -f "$opath" ]]
         then
            cd $odir
            ndir=$(pwd -P)
            nbase=$(basename "$opath")
            retval=0
            #done
        else
            echo "$FUNCNAME: ERROR: unknown condition outside link!!" >&2
            echo "opath [[ $opath ]]" >&2
            return 1
        fi
    fi
    #now assemble our output
    echo -n "$ndir"
    if [[ "x${nbase:=}" != "x" ]]
     then
        echo "/$nbase"
    else 
        echo
    fi
    #now return to where we were
    cd "$owd"
    return $retval
}
```

here's a classic example, thanks to brew:

```
%% ls -l `which mvn`
lrwxr-xr-x  1 draistrick  502  29 Dec 17 10:50 /usr/local/bin/mvn@ -> ../Cellar/maven/3.2.3/bin/mvn
```

use this function and it will return the -real- path:

```
%% cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
. resolve_path.inc
echo
echo "relative symlinked path:"
which mvn
echo
echo "and the real path:"
resolve_path `which mvn`


%% test.sh

relative symlinked path:
/usr/local/bin/mvn

and the real path:
/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.2.3/libexec/bin/mvn
```

Comment: My earlier answer does exactly the same thing in about 1/4 of the space :) It's pretty basic shell scripting and not worthy of a git repo.

Answer (score 0):

Here I present what I believe to be a cross-platform (Linux and macOS at least) solution to the answer that is working well for me currently.

```
crosspath()
{
    local ref="$1"
    if [ -x "$(which realpath)" ]; then
        path="$(realpath "$ref")"
    else
        path="$(readlink -f "$ref" 2> /dev/null)"
        if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
            if [ -x "$(which readlink)" ]; then
                if [ ! -z "$(readlink "$ref")" ]; then
                    ref="$(readlink "$ref")"
                fi
            else
                echo "realpath and readlink not available. The following may not be the final path." 1>&2
            fi
            if [ -d "$ref" ]; then
                path="$(cd "$ref"; pwd -P)"
            else
                path="$(cd $(dirname "$ref"); pwd -P)/$(basename "$ref")"
            fi
        fi
    fi
    echo "$path"
}
```

Here is a macOS (only?) solution. Possibly better suited to the original question.

```
mac_realpath()
{
    local ref="$1"
    if [[ ! -z "$(readlink "$ref")" ]]; then
        ref="$(readlink "$1")"
    fi
    if [[ -d "$ref" ]]; then
        echo "$(cd "$ref"; pwd -P)"
    else
        echo "$(cd $(dirname "$ref"); pwd -P)/$(basename "$ref")"
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer here [Bash: how to get real path of a symlink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29789204/bash-how-to-get-real-path-of-a-symlink/55254754#55254754)

but in short very handy in scripts:

```
script_home=$( dirname $(realpath "$0") )
echo Original script home: $script_home
```

These are part of GNU coreutils, suitable for use in Linux systems.

To test everything, we put symlink into /home/test2/, amend some additional things and run/call it from root directory:

```
/$ /home/test2/symlink
/home/test
Original script home: /home/test
```

Where

```
Original script is: /home/test/realscript.sh
Called script is: /home/test2/symlink
```

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents. This function is POSIX compliant, and both the source and the destination can contain `->`. However, I have not gotten it work with filenames that container newline or tabs, as `ls` in general has issues with those.

```
resolve_symlink() {
  test -L "$1" && ls -l "$1" | awk -v SYMLINK="$1" '{ SL=(SYMLINK)" -> "; i=index($0, SL); s=substr($0, i+length(SL)); print s }'
}
```

I believe the solution here is the `file` command, with a custom magic file that only outputs the destination of the provided symlink.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution, tested in Bash 3.2.57:

```
# Read a path (similar to `readlink`) recursively, until the physical path without any links (like `cd -P`) is found.
# Accepts any existing path, prints its physical path and exits `0`, exits `1` if some contained links don't exist.
# Motivation: `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` often contains links; using it directly to extract your project's path may fail.
#
# Example: Safely `source` a file located relative to the current script
#
#     source "$(dirname "$(rreadlink "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")")/relative/script.sh"
#Inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51089005/6307827
rreadlink () {
    declare p="$1" d l
    while :; do
        d="$(cd -P "$(dirname "$p")" && pwd)" || return $? #absolute path without symlinks
        p="$d/$(basename "$p")"
        if [ -h "$p" ]; then
            l="$(readlink "$p")" || break

            #A link must be resolved from its fully resolved parent dir.
            d="$(cd "$d" && cd -P "$(dirname "$l")" && pwd)" || return $?
            p="$d/$(basename "$l")"
        else
            break
        fi
    done
    printf '%s\n' "$p"
}
```