# How best to include other scripts?

Tags: bash

The way you would normally include a script is with "source"

eg:

main.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

source incl.sh

echo "The main script"
```

incl.sh:

```
echo "The included script"
```

The output of executing "./main.sh" is:

```
The included script
The main script
```

... Now, if you attempt to execute that shell script from another location, it can't find the include unless it's in your path.

What's a good way to ensure that your script can find the include script, especially if for instance, the script needs to be portable?

Comment: see this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in

Comment: Related / also answering this question, by the way: here is my answer on how to get the `SCRIPT_DIRECTORY` path of the script being run, so you can use it to import ([via `source` or `.`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62626515/4561887)) other scripts relative to the current script: [How can I get the source directory of a Bash script from within the script itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60157372/4561887). (My answer there is so far down the list, having this link will save you some scrolling there too :)). My answer there can be considered a variation of the accepted answer here.

Answer (score 269, accepted):

I tend to make my scripts all be relative to one another. 
That way I can use dirname:

```
#!/bin/sh

my_dir="$(dirname "$0")"

"$my_dir/other_script.sh"
```

Comment: This will not work if the script is executed through $PATH. then `which $0` will be useful

Comment: There is no reliable way to determine the location of a shell script, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028

Comment: @Philipp, The author of that entry is correct, it is complex, and there are gotchas. But it's missing some key points, first, the author assumes a whole lot of things about what you are going to be doing with your bash script. I wouldn't expect a python script to run without it's dependencies either. Bash is a glue language that allows you to do things quickly that would be hard otherwise. When you need your build system to work, pragmatism (And a nice warning about the script not being able to find dependencies) wins.

Comment: This will not work when an included script needs to include another, since $0 is set to "-bash". Anybody knows a solution for this case?

Comment: Just learned about `BASH_SOURCE` array, and how the first element in this array always points to the current source.

Comment: This will not work if the scripts are different locations. e.g. /home/me/main.sh calls /home/me/test/inc.sh as dirname will return /home/me. sacii answer using BASH_SOURCE is a better solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/12694189/1000011

Comment: No good. BASH_SOURCE is better:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192292/bash-how-best-to-include-other-scripts/12694189#12694189

Comment: Hint: use `source "$my_dir/other_script.sh"` (with bash) to execute the script in the current shell.

Comment: BASH_SOURCE sounds great... for bash. Although somehow, I have a feeling it isn't very portable. If you really want the location of the script, use findutils with a unique name.

Comment: $0 would give included script, whereas `source` way gives original.

Answer (score 241):

I know I am late to the party, but this should work no matter how you start the script and uses builtins exclusively:

```
DIR="${BASH_SOURCE%/*}"
if [[ ! -d "$DIR" ]]; then DIR="$PWD"; fi
. "$DIR/incl.sh"
. "$DIR/main.sh"
```

`.` (dot) command is an alias to `source`, `$PWD` is the Path for the Working Directory, `BASH_SOURCE` is an array variable whose members are the source filenames, `${string%substring}` strips shortest match of $substring from back of $string

Comment: This is the only answer in the thread that consistently worked for me

Comment: This is the answer! I would only make it a method, or an alias, rather than a variable (included scripts would rewrite the variable in a parent script if they used the same mechanism to include their  subscripts).

Comment: @sacii May I know when is the line `if [[ ! -d "$DIR" ]]; then DIR="$PWD"; fi` needed?  I can find a need for it if the commands are being pasted to a bash prompt to run.  However, if running inside a script file context, I can't see a need for it...

Comment: It is also worth noting that it works as expected across multiple `source`s (i mean, if you `source` a script that `source`s another in another directory and so on, it still works).

Comment: Shouldn't this be `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` as you only want the latest called? Also, using `DIR=$(dirname ${BASH_SOURCE[0]})` will allow you to get rid of the if-condition

Comment: I don't like this bash specific implementation which is not working with zsh

Comment: This fails if you invoke the script from the script directory with `$ bash script.sh` where a leading dot is not included in `$BASH_SOURCE` and `DIR` resolves to `script.sh` whereas `$(dirname $BASH_SOURCE)` correctly resolves to `.`

Comment: Both `${BASH_SOURCE%/*}` and `$(dirname ${BASH_SOURCE[0]})` worked for me. This worked consistently both in files that were `source`d or executed via `./<file>` in several different configurations (unlike the accepted answer).

Comment: And I still thinks this is terrible. I wish there would be just one liner for this without worrying if this will work in nested imports, current or working dir, functions etc.

Comment: Are you willing to make this snippet available under a no attribute required license, like [CC0](https://creativecommons.org/share-your-work/public-domain/cc0/) or just release it into the public domain? I'd like to use this verbatim but it's annoying to put the attribution at the top of every single script!

Comment: `DIR=$(dirname $BASH_SOURCE)` is best!

Answer (score 59):

An alternative to:

```
scriptPath=$(dirname $0)
```

is:

```
scriptPath=${0%/*}
```

.. the advantage being not having the dependence on dirname, which is not a built-in command (and not always available in emulators)

Comment: `basePath=$(dirname $0)` gave me blank value when the containing script file is sourced.

Answer (score 53):

If it is in the same directory you can use `dirname $0`:

```
#!/bin/bash

source $(dirname $0)/incl.sh

echo "The main script"
```

Comment: Two pitfalls: 1) `$0` is `./t.sh` and dirname returns `.`; 2) after `cd bin` the returned `.` is not correct. `$BASH_SOURCE` is no better.

Comment: another pitfall: try this with spaces in directory name.

Comment: `source "$(dirname $0)/incl.sh"` works for those cases

Answer (score 32):

I think the best way to do this is to use the Chris Boran's way, BUT you should compute MY_DIR this way:

```
#!/bin/sh
MY_DIR=$(dirname $(readlink -f $0))
$MY_DIR/other_script.sh
```

To quote the man pages for readlink:

> ```
> readlink - display value of a symbolic link
>
> ...
>
>   -f, --canonicalize
>         canonicalize  by following every symlink in every component of the given 
>         name recursively; all but the last component must exist
> ```

I've never encountered a use case where `MY_DIR` is not correctly computed. If you access your script through a symlink in your `$PATH` it works.

Comment: Nice and simple solution, and works famously for me in as many variations of script invocation that I could think of. Thanks.

Comment: Aside from issues with missing quotes, is there any actual use case where you would want to resolve the symbolic links rather than use `$0` directly?

Comment: @l0b0:
Imagine your script is `/home/you/script.sh`
You can `cd /home` and run your script from there as `./you/script.sh`
In this case `dirname $0` will return `./you` and including other script will fail

Comment: Great suggestion, however, I needed to do the following in order for it
to read my variables in 
`
    `MY_DIR=$(dirname $(readlink -f $0)); 
    source $MY_DIR/incl.sh`

Answer (score 26):

**A combination of the answers to this question provides the most robust solution.**

It worked for us in production-grade scripts with great support of dependencies and directory structure:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Full path of the current script
THIS=`readlink -f "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" 2>/dev/null||echo $0`

# The directory where current script resides
DIR=`dirname "${THIS}"`

# 'Dot' means 'source', i.e. 'include':
. "$DIR/compile.sh"
```

**The method supports all of these:**

- **Spaces** in path
- **Links** (via `readlink`)
- `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` is more robust than `$0`

Comment: THIS=`readlink -f "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" 2>/dev/null||echo $0`  if your readlink is BusyBox v1.01

Comment: @AlexxRoche thank you! Will this work on all Linuxes?

Comment: I would expect so. Seems to work on Debian Sid 3.16 and QNAP's armv5tel 3.4.6 Linux.

Comment: I put it in this one line: `DIR=$(dirname $(readlink -f "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" 2>/dev/null||echo $0))  # https://stackoverflow.com/a/34208365/`

Answer (score 23):

```
SRC=$(cd $(dirname "$0"); pwd)
source "${SRC}/incl.sh"
```

Comment: I suspect that you got down voted for the "cd ..." when dirname "$0" should accomplish the same thing...

Comment: This code will return absolute path even when script is executed from current directory. $(dirname "$0") alone will return just "."

Comment: And `./incl.sh` resolves to the same path as `cd` + `pwd`. So what is the advantage of changing the directory?

Comment: Sometimes you need the absolute path of the script, e.g. when you have to change directories back and forth.

Comment: Thanks for adding this. All the dirname usage alone was making me itch :) I learned this from mentors yrs ago, but with the mildly diff form of DIR="$(cd "$(dirname $0)" && pwd)"

Answer (score 19):

## 1. Neatest

I explored almost every suggestion and here is the neatest one that worked for me:

`script_root=$(dirname $(readlink -f $0))`

It works even when the script is symlinked to a `$PATH` directory.

See it in action here: https://github.com/pendashteh/hcagent/blob/master/bin/hcagent

## 2. The coolest

```
# Copyright https://stackoverflow.com/a/13222994/257479
script_root=$(ls -l /proc/$$/fd | grep "255 ->" | sed -e 's/^.\+-> //')
```

This is actually from another answer on this very page, but I'm adding it to my answer too!

## 3. The most reliable

Alternatively, in the rare case that those didn't work, here is the bullet proof approach:

```
# Copyright http://stackoverflow.com/a/7400673/257479
myreadlink() { [ ! -h "$1" ] && echo "$1" || (local link="$(expr "$(command ls -ld -- "$1")" : '.*-> \(.*\)$')"; cd $(dirname $1); myreadlink "$link" | sed "s|^\([^/].*\)\$|$(dirname $1)/\1|"); }
whereis() { echo $1 | sed "s|^\([^/].*/.*\)|$(pwd)/\1|;s|^\([^/]*\)$|$(which -- $1)|;s|^$|$1|"; } 
whereis_realpath() { local SCRIPT_PATH=$(whereis $1); myreadlink ${SCRIPT_PATH} | sed "s|^\([^/].*\)\$|$(dirname ${SCRIPT_PATH})/\1|"; } 

script_root=$(dirname $(whereis_realpath "$0"))
```

You can see it in action in `taskrunner` source: https://github.com/pendashteh/taskrunner/blob/master/bin/taskrunner

Hope this help someone out there :)

Also, please leave it as a comment if one did not work for you and mention your operating system and emulator. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

This works even if the script is sourced:

```
source "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )/incl.sh"
```

Comment: Could you explain what is the purpose of the "[0]"?

Comment: @Ray `BASH_SOURCE` is an array of paths, corresponding to a call-stack. The first element corresponds to the most recent script in the stack, which is the currently executing script. Actually, `$BASH_SOURCE` called as a variable expands to its first element by default, so `[0]` is not necessary here. See [this link](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028) for details.

Answer (score 8):

You need to specify the location of the other scripts, there is no other way around it.  I'd recommend a configurable variable at the top of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
installpath=/where/your/scripts/are

. $installpath/incl.sh

echo "The main script"
```

Alternatively, you can insist that the user maintain an environment variable indicating where your program home is at, like PROG_HOME or somesuch.  This can be supplied for the user automatically by creating a script with that information in /etc/profile.d/, which will be sourced every time a user logs in.

Comment: I appreciate the desire for specificity, but I can't see why the full path should be required unless the include scripts were part of another package. I don't see a security difference loading from a specific relative path (i.e. same dir where the script is executing.) vs a specific fullpath. Why do you say there's no way around it?

Comment: Because the directory where your script is executing is not necessarily where the scripts you want to include in your script are located.  You want to load the scripts where they are installed at and there is no reliable way to tell where that is at run-time.  Not using a fixed location is also a good way to include the wrong (i.e. hacker supplied) script and run it.

Comment: Using a relative path from a running scripts location is reliable at runtime. And the absolute canonical path to $0 can be reliably found with $(cd "$(dirname $0)" && pwd)" which can also be used to canonicalize the library dir: "$(cd "$(cd "$(dirname $0)" && pwd)/../lib" && pwd)"

Answer (score 7):

I'd suggest that you create a setenv script whose sole purpose is to provide locations for various components across your system.

All other scripts would then source this script so that all locations are common across all scripts using the setenv script.

This is very useful when running cronjobs. You get a minimal environment when running cron, but if you make all cron scripts first include the setenv script then you are able to control and synchronise the environment that you want the cronjobs to execute in.

We used such a technique on our build monkey that was used for continuous integration across a project of about 2,000 kSLOC.

Answer (score 4):

**[Shell Script Loader](http://loader.sourceforge.net/)** is my solution for this.

It provides a function named include() that can be called many times in many scripts to refer a single script but will only load the script once. The function can accept complete paths or partial paths (script is searched in a search path). A similar function named load() is also provided that will load the scripts unconditionally.

It works for **bash**, **ksh**, **pd ksh** and **zsh with** optimized scripts for each one of them; and other shells that are generically compatible with the original sh like **ash**, **dash**, **heirloom sh**, etc., through a universal script that automatically optimizes its functions depending on the features the shell can provide.

**[Fowarded example]**

**start.sh**

This is an optional starter script. Placing the startup methods here is just a convenience and can be placed in the main script instead. This script is also not needed if the scripts are to be compiled.

```
#!/bin/sh

# load loader.sh
. loader.sh

# include directories to search path
loader_addpath /usr/lib/sh deps source

# load main script
load main.sh
```

**main.sh**

```
include a.sh
include b.sh

echo '---- main.sh ----'

# remove loader from shellspace since
# we no longer need it
loader_finish

# main procedures go from here

# ...
```

**a.sh**

```
include main.sh
include a.sh
include b.sh

echo '---- a.sh ----'
```

**b.sh**

```
include main.sh
include a.sh
include b.sh

echo '---- b.sh ----'
```

**output:**

```
---- b.sh ----
---- a.sh ----
---- main.sh ----
```

What's best is scripts based on it may also be compiled to form a single script with the available compiler.

Here's a project that uses it: http://sourceforge.net/p/playshell/code/ci/master/tree/. It can run portably with or without compiling the scripts. Compiling to produce a single script can also happen, and is helpful during installation.

I also created a simpler prototype for any conservative party that may want to have a brief idea of how an implementation script works: https://sourceforge.net/p/loader/code/ci/base/tree/loader-include-prototype.bash. It's small and anyone can just include the code in their main script if they want to if their code is intended to run with Bash 4.0 or newer, and it also doesn't use `eval`.

Comment: 12 kilobytes of Bash script containing over 100 lines of `eval`ed code to load dependencies. *Ouch*

Comment: @l0b0 If you mean about the scripts provided there, eval'ed code applies only as help for the generic form. Bash and other modern shells don't need it. I assume you read the universal one i.e. `loader.sh`?

Comment: Exactly one of the three `eval` blocks near the bottom is always run. So whether it's needed or not, it sure is using `eval`.

Comment: That eval call is safe and it's not used if you have Bash 4.0+. I see, you are one of those old-time scripters who think `eval` is pure evil, and doesn't know how to make good use of it instead.

Comment: Perhaps you could actually suggest a better solution for "flagging" a script for shells not supporting associative arrays? :)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "not used", but **it is run.** And after some years of shell scripting as part of my job, yes, I'm more convinced than ever that `eval` is evil.

Comment: Two portable, simple ways to flag files come to mind instantly: Either referring to them by their inode number, or by putting NUL-separated paths into a file.

Comment: I won't argue with `eval` being evil these days as it's now more like a religion. There are just many ways to prove that eval is not as unsafe as people usually think it is e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18125979/445221. It just depends on the scripter really if he knows what he's doing.

Comment: I don't think any shell script can portably scan inode numbers? And I hope you don't actually consider a slow IO solution for flagging, or even yet using external tools? Maybe you even intend to use db.

Answer (score 3):

Steve's reply is definitely the correct technique but it should be refactored so that your installpath variable is in a separate environment script where all such declarations are made.

Then all scripts source that script and should installpath change, you only need to change it in one location. Makes things more, er, futureproof. God I hate that word! (-:

BTW You should really refer to the variable using ${installpath} when using it in the way shown in your example:

```
. ${installpath}/incl.sh
```

If the braces are left out, some shells will try and expand the variable "installpath/incl.sh"!

Answer (score 2):

I put all my startup scripts in a .bashrc.d directory.
This is a common technique in such places as /etc/profile.d, etc.

```
while read file; do source "${file}"; done <<HERE
$(find ${HOME}/.bashrc.d -type f)
HERE
```

The problem with the solution using globbing...

```
for file in ${HOME}/.bashrc.d/*.sh; do source ${file};done
```

...is you might have a file list which is "too long".
An approach like...

```
find ${HOME}/.bashrc.d -type f | while read file; do source ${file}; done
```

...runs but doesn't change the environment as desired.

Answer (score 2):

This should work reliably:

```
source_relative() {
 local dir="${BASH_SOURCE%/*}"
 [[ -z "$dir" ]] && dir="$PWD"
 source "$dir/$1"
}

source_relative incl.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Using source or $0 will not give you the real path of your script. You could use the process id of the script to retrieve its real path

```
ls -l       /proc/$$/fd           | 
grep        "255 ->"            |
sed -e      's/^.\+-> //'
```

I am using this script and it has always served me well :)

Answer (score 1):

Of course, to each their own, but I think the block below is pretty solid. I believe this involves the "best" way to find a directory, and the "best" way to call another bash script:

```
scriptdir=`dirname "$BASH_SOURCE"`
source $scriptdir/incl.sh

echo "The main script"
```

So this may be the "best" way to include other scripts. This is based off another "best" answer that [tells a bash script where it is stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in)

Answer (score 1):

Personally put all libraries in a `lib` folder and use an `import` function to load them.

*folder structure*

[image]

*`script.sh` contents*

```
# Imports '.sh' files from 'lib' directory
function import()
{
  local file="./lib/$1.sh"
  local error="\e[31mError: \e[0mCannot find \e[1m$1\e[0m library at: \e[2m$file\e[0m"
  if [ -f "$file" ]; then
     source "$file"
    if [ -z $IMPORTED ]; then
      echo -e $error
      exit 1
    fi
  else
    echo -e $error
    exit 1
  fi
}
```

Note that this import function should be at the beginning of your script and then you can easily import your libraries like this:

```
import "utils"
import "requirements"
```

Add a single line at the top of each library (i.e. utils.sh):

```
IMPORTED="$BASH_SOURCE"
```

Now you have access to functions inside `utils.sh` and `requirements.sh` from `script.sh`

TODO: Write a linker to build a single `sh` file

Comment: Does this also solve the problem of executing the script outside of the dir it is in?

Comment: @AaronH. No. It is a structured way for including dependencies in large projects.

Answer (score 0):

we just need to find out the folder where our incl.sh and main.sh is stored; just change your main.sh with this:

main.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

SCRIPT_NAME=$(basename $0)
SCRIPT_DIR="$(echo $0| sed "s/$SCRIPT_NAME//g")"
source $SCRIPT_DIR/incl.sh

echo "The main script"
```

Comment: Incorrect quoting, unnecessary use of `echo`, and incorrect use of `sed`'s `g` option. -1.

Comment: Anyway, to get this script work do: `SCRIPT_DIR=$(echo "$0" | sed "s/${SCRIPT_NAME}//")` and then
`source "${SCRIPT_DIR}incl.sh"`

Answer (score 0):

According [`man hier`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/hier.7.html) suitable place for script includes is `/usr/local/lib/`

> /usr/local/lib
>
> Files associated with locally installed programs.

Personally I prefer `/usr/local/lib/bash/includes` for includes.
There is [bash-helper](https://github.com/nafigator/bash-helpers#features) lib for including libs in that way:

```
#!/bin/bash

. /usr/local/lib/bash/includes/bash-helpers.sh

include api-client || exit 1                   # include shared functions
include mysql-status/query-builder || exit 1   # include script functions

# include script functions with status message
include mysql-status/process-checker; status 'process-checker' $? || exit 1
include mysql-status/nonexists; status 'nonexists' $? || exit 1
```

[image: bash-helpers includes status output]

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers I saw here seem to overcomplicate things. This method has always worked reliably for me:

```
FULLPATH=$(readlink -f $0)
INCPATH=${FULLPATH%/*}
```

INCPATH will hold the complete path of the script excluding the script filename, regardless of how the script is called (by $PATH, relative or absolute).

After that, one only needs to do this to include files in the same directory:

```
. $INCPATH/file_to_include.sh
```

Reference: [TecPorto / Location independent includes](https://tecporto.pt/wiki/index.php/Location_independent_includes)

Answer (score 0):

here is a nice function you can use. it builds on what @sacii made. thank you

it will let you list any number of space separated script names to source (relative to the script calling `source_files`).

optionally you can pass an absolute or relative path as the first argument and it will source from there instead.

you can call it multiple times (see example below) to source scripts from different dirs

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function source_files() {
  local scripts_dir
  scripts_dir="$1"

  if [ -d "$scripts_dir" ]; then
    shift
  else
    scripts_dir="${BASH_SOURCE%/*}"
    if [[ ! -d "$scripts_dir" ]]; then scripts_dir="$PWD"; fi
  fi

  for script_name in "$@"; do
    # shellcheck disable=SC1091 disable=SC1090
    . "$scripts_dir/$script_name.sh"
  done
}
```

here is an example you can run to show how its used

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function source_files() {
  local scripts_dir
  scripts_dir="$1"

  if [ -d "$scripts_dir" ]; then
    shift
  else
    scripts_dir="${BASH_SOURCE%/*}"
    if [[ ! -d "$scripts_dir" ]]; then scripts_dir="$PWD"; fi
  fi

  for script_name in "$@"; do
    # shellcheck disable=SC1091 disable=SC1090
    . "$scripts_dir/$script_name.sh"
  done
}

## -- EXAMPLE -- ##
# assumes dir structure:
# /
#   source_files.sh
#   sibling.sh
#   scripts/
#     child.sh
#   nested/
#     scripts/
#       grandchild.sh

cd /tmp || exit 1

# sibling.sh
tee sibling.sh <<- EOF > /dev/null 
  #!/usr/bin/env bash
  
  export SIBLING_VAR='sibling var value'
EOF

# scripts/child.sh
mkdir -p scripts
tee scripts/child.sh <<- EOF > /dev/null
  #!/usr/bin/env bash

  export CHILD_VAR='child var value'
EOF

# nested/scripts/grandchild.sh
mkdir -p nested/scripts
tee nested/scripts/grandchild.sh <<- EOF > /dev/null
  #!/usr/bin/env bash

  export GRANDCHILD_VAR='grandchild var value'
EOF

source_files 'sibling'
source_files 'scripts' 'child'
source_files 'nested/scripts' 'grandchild'

echo "$SIBLING_VAR"
echo "$CHILD_VAR"
echo "$GRANDCHILD_VAR"

rm sibling.sh
rm -rf scripts nested

cd - || exit 1
```

prints:

```bash
sibling var value
child var value
grandchild var value
```

Answer (score -5):

You can also use:

```
PWD=$(pwd)
source "$PWD/inc.sh"
```

Comment: You assume that you are in the same directory where scripts are located. It won't work if you are somewhere else.