# simple bash script to execute python code

Tags: bash, shell

I am noob in bash script and I am trying to do the following..

I have a directory structure like

```
root/
root/execute.sh
root/python/foo.py
```

I want to execute foo.py 
I did something like following in `execute.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
cd python
python foo.py
```

But it throws an error that `foo.py` is not there.
How do i fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659689/referring-to-a-file-relative-to-executing-script

Comment: how are you running execute.sh?

Comment: @xvan `./execute.sh`

Comment: I couldn't reproduce, try adding `pwd` and `ls` to the shell script, after `cd python` to make sure that `foo.py` is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script you should try

```
python ./foo.py
```

Or you add the directory /root/python to root's PATH-variable. You can do this in the users .bashrc file by adding

```
PATH=$PATH:/root/python
export PATH
```

Hope that helps.

Best,

me

Comment: Do you know why plain `python foo.py` doesn't work for him?

Comment: If you want to run a script within the current directory you need to use ./ , otherwise the system trys to find it in the users PATHs

Comment: Is that a python3 thing? At least python2 doesn't require ./

Comment: I made a mistake in my explanation. my explanation generally refers to the execution of executables on *nix systems. I had the time to test the given scenario, now. With my systems (archlinux and debian) I did not get any errors. I have tested with python 2 and 3.