# How do I reference the current directory inside a terminal command file?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, command-line, terminal

I'm creating a **.command** file (with macOS) that I want to be able to drop into any folder and have it create a **.txt** file *relative* to what ever folder it exists in.

Eg.

```
cd .
echo -e "write this to the log" >> log.txt
exit
```

The above doesn't work though. I've also tried `cd pwd`.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: "cd pwd" doesn't make any sense, since you are already in the current dir. What's your true purpose? Give us some examples, so that we can figure out your problem.

Comment: The "current directory" is not generally the directory the script is located in; it's inherited from the current working directory of the process that ran the script, so it could be almost anything. If you double-click a .command script in macOS, it's run by a process whose working directory is your home folder. For the script's folder, see ["Referring to a file relative to executing script"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659689/referring-to-a-file-relative-to-executing-script), and [BashFAQ #28](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028).