# Check if file exist relative to current script (one level up)

Tags: bash, shell

How to check/get file path relative to current script?

Script is running from `..../app/scripts/dev.sh`

File to check from `..../app/dist/file.js`

```
dir="${BASH_SOURCE%/*}../dist/backend.js"
if [ -f ${dir} ]; then
    echo "file exists. ${dir}"
else 
    echo "file does not exist. ${dir}"
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three problems in your script.

1. To store the output of a command in a variable, use `$()`, not `${}`.
2. `[ -f "$dir" ]` checks if `$dir` is a a *file*, which  will never happen, because `dirname` outputs a directory.
3. Your script can be executed from any other working directory as well. Just because the script is stored in `···/app/scripts/` does not mean it will always run from there.

Try

```
file=$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")/../dist/file.js
if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    echo "file exists."
else 
    echo "file does not exist."
fi
```

Comment: problem is that pwd is different, so i need to use `./dist/backend.js` to work(one dot), but I want to use relative path from script location to be able to run script from anywhere

Comment: Then your question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/6659689/6770384

Comment: I don't get how to go one level up :(

Comment: @ZiiMakc You can use `..` on any directory of a path to go one level up. For example `a/b/c/../../b/../b/` is the same as `a/b/`. See my edited answer.