# How to include file in a bash shell script

Tags: linux, bash, include

Is there a way to include another shell script in a shell script to be able to access its functions?

Like how in PHP you can use the `include` directive with other PHP files in order to run the functions that are contained within simply by calling the function name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash: How _best_ to include other scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192292/bash-how-best-to-include-other-scripts)

Comment: @Troubadour thanks for the reference. Even though the post refers to the `source` command, the question in itself is asking how to pinpoint the location of a `source` file.

Answer (score 260, accepted):

Simply put inside your script :

```
source FILE
```

Or

```
. FILE # POSIX compliant
```

```
$ LANG=C help source
source: source filename [arguments]
Execute commands from a file in the current shell.

Read and execute commands from FILENAME in the current shell.  The
entries in $PATH are used to find the directory containing FILENAME.
If any ARGUMENTS are supplied, they become the positional parameters
when FILENAME is executed.

Exit Status:
Returns the status of the last command executed in FILENAME; fails if
FILENAME cannot be read.
```

Comment: Note that . is POSIX compliant whereas source isn't

Comment: But here source is not exactly the include same as we do in `C` language. Here source is executing the child script into the main script. What if I just want to call a particular function from the child script?

Comment: Don't confuse `. script.sh` with `./script.sh`. I lost hours trying to figure out what is going on

Comment: While . is POSIX compliant, which means it will work on sh, dash, zsh and other POSIX shells. It's better to use . as some shells have their own, similar, but a bit different version of "source" which may break your app.

Comment: Can we consider `. other.sh` equivalent to a copy and paste of the other script into the parent script or are there any subtle differences?

Answer (score 83):

Above answers are correct, but if you run script in another folder, there will be some problem.

For example, `a.sh` and `b.sh` are in same folder,
a use `. ./b.sh` to include b.

When you run script out of the folder, for example, `xx/xx/xx/a.sh`, file `b.sh` will not found: `./b.sh: No such file or directory`.

So I use

```
. $(dirname "$0")/b.sh
```

Comment: This only works for one level of source/include. If `b.sh` further includes a `c.sh` using `. $(dirname "$0")/c.sh`, then it will fail miserably because while sourcing/including b, `$0` is the shell itself, and I am not aware of any method till date to figure out the directory of `b.sh`

Answer (score 39):

Yes, use [source](http://ss64.com/bash/period.html) or the short form which is just `.`:

```
. other_script.sh
```

Comment: Note the `.` version works on `sh` as well as Bash. The "source" one only works in Bash.

Answer (score 10):

Syntax is `source <file-name>`

ex. `source config.sh`

script - config.sh

```
USERNAME="satish"
EMAIL="satish@linuxconcept.com"
```

calling script -

```
#!/bin/bash
source config.sh
echo Welcome ${USERNAME}!
echo Your email is ${EMAIL}.
```

You can learn to [include a bash script in another bash script here](https://linuxconcept.com/how-to-include-bash-script-in-other-bash-script/).

Answer (score 4):

In my situation, in order to include `color.sh` from the same directory in `init.sh`, I had to do something as follows.

```
. ./color.sh
```

Not sure why the `./` and not `color.sh` directly. The content of `color.sh` is as follows.

```
RED=`tput setaf 1`
GREEN=`tput setaf 2`
BLUE=`tput setaf 4`
BOLD=`tput bold`
RESET=`tput sgr0`
```

Making use of `File color.sh` does not error but, the color do not display. I have tested this in `Ubuntu 18.04` and the `Bash` version is:

`GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: That'll just give you the file in your current working directory, not the directory where `init.sh` is (they coincide if you launched it with `./init.sh` in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

To further source in the sourced file you might set the PATH:

```
export PATH=$(dirname $0):$PATH

. b.sh
```

N.B. of course beware of spaces in directorynames.