# How to change path to fix error "./main: error while loading shared library libmkl_core.so?

Tags: c++, linux, path, shared-libraries, intel-mkl

I have installed intel mkl library. contents have path /home/user/intel/..... . I have to run a C++ code using make file on which it is mentioned.

```make
CC = /home/user/intel/bin/icpc -g
INCLUDE = -I/home/user/intel/mkl/include 
LIB = -L/home/user/intel/mkl/lib/intel64 -lmkl_core -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_intel_thread -liomp5 -lpthread -std=c++11
```

I have successfully installed parallel_studio_xe_2019_update5_cluster_edition . but still I'm getting an error message that ./main :error while loading shared libraries. How can I fix this error. What changes I need to do?

Comment: Did you follow the MKL documentation, namely that [part for setting environment variables by including a given script](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-linux-developer-guide-scripts-to-set-environment-variables) (such as `mklvars.sh`) in your environment?

Comment: I only run install_GUI.sh in the terminal. But where can I find mklvars.sh intel64

Comment: Yes, you should include that script in your Bash session, see here how: [How to include file in a bash shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10823635/580083). A common way is to put this inclusion into a Bash startup script (sucha a `~/.bashrc`) to apply it automatically to all Bash sessions.

Comment: Before running your application, at the shell, try this: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/path/to/your/library`

Comment: For me its hard to grasp this explanation. Can you please explain it with some easy language.I compile my code simply by writing make, what will be /path/to/your/library in my case ?

Comment: @huda_ Only you can know it. but it seems to be `/home/user/intel/mkl/lib/intel64`

Comment: In my case it is "/home/user/intel/mkl/lib/intel64". I have modified the path makefile. But stil getting same error

Comment: Also see [Why audo /sbin/ldconfig -v doesn't fix the ./main: error while loading shared libraries: libmkl_core.so](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58026938/608639)

Comment: What is your code doing? Is there any run-time dynamic loading of shared object (using e.g. `dlopen`)?

Answer (score 3):

Linking with shared libraries is actually done in two steps: When building (where the linker needs to find the library); And when running (when the operating system dynamic loaded needs to find the library).

When building with libraries installed in non-standard locations, you tell the linker where to find the library using the `-L` option. Unfortunately it doesn't tell the dynamic loader where the library is located.

To tell the dynamic loader the location of a dynamic library there are a couple of way, the one I recommend is to add a flag when building so the linker will embed the location inside the executable program file for the dynamic loader to see. This is done with the option `-Wl,-rpath,/path/to/lib/directory`.

In your case you need to add the option `-Wl,-rpath,/home/user/intel/mkl/lib/intel64` to the `LIB` makefile variable.

---

To clarify, the *full* line should be

```
LIB = -L/home/user/intel/mkl/lib/intel64 -Wl,-rpath,/home/user/intel/mkl/lib/intel64 -lmkl_core -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_intel_thread -liomp5 -lpthread -std=c++11
```

That is, you need *both* the old `-L` option (as you current have it in the code you show) *and* add the new option.

Comment: But then how and where should I  need to define rpath?

Comment: @huda_ ***Almost***, `-Wl` with `l` as in lower-case `L`. And you still need the `-L` option for the linker to find the libraries.

Comment: I edited like this: LIB = -L//-Wl,rpath//home/tqc04/intel/mkl/lib/intel64 -lmkl_core -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_intel_thread -liomp5 -lpthread -std=c++11  . But still can't fix this error.I never met with such type of problem. I mistakenly deleted some files in home directory after which i'm facing this problem

Comment: @huda_ You're misunderstanding what I mean. See my updated answer

Comment: I mentioned that line but still getting same error.

Comment: I'm getting the same error even after modifying LIB as you mentioned

Comment: @huda_ Then you're doing something else wrong. Please edit your question to show us the *complete* makefile, and the *complete* build log (including the commands that run with their flags).