# Grep multiple bash parameters

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I'm writing a bash script which shall search in multiple files.

The problem I'm encountering is that I can't egrep an undetermined number of variables passed as parameters to the bash script

I want it to do the following:

Given a random number of parameters. i.e:

```
./searchline.sh A B C
```

Do a grep on the first one, and egrep the result with the rest:

```
grep "A" * | egrep B | egrep C
```

What I've tried to do is to build a string with the egreps:

```
for j in "${@:2}";
do
ADDITIONALSEARCH="$ADDITIONALSEARCH | egrep $j";
done

grep "$1" * "$ADDITIONALSEARCH"
```

But somehow that won't work, it seems like bash is not treating the "egrep" string as an egrep.

Do you guys have any advice?

By the way, as a side note, I'm not able to create any auxiliary file so grep -f is out of the line I guess. Also note, that the number of parameters passed to the bash script is variable, so I can't do egrep "$2" | egrep "$3".

Thanks in advance.

Fernando

Comment: @fedorqui: '|' means OR, not and. When you pipe egrep, you want the intersection of the patterns, so an AND.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A safe `eval` can be a good solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; then
    temp=(egrep -e "\"\$1\"" '*')

    for (( i = 2; i <= $#; ++i )); do
        temp+=('|' egrep -e "\"\${$i}\"")
    done

    eval "${temp[@]}"
fi
```

To run it:

```
bash script.sh A B C
```

Comment: Wow, a use of `eval` that (at least as far as I can see) actually *is* safe! +1 for you, sir.

Comment: What's the value of defining `temp` as an array when eval is just going to concatenate it back into a single string before running that string through the parser?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Preference. Also I think it's more efficient when the list of elements grows. A list is better that a repeatedly concatenated string. Also I might just use normal variables sometimes. Either method is fine. It's just up to you which you think is more convenient to write, although this time I think the use of an array is better.

Answer (score 4):

You can use recursion here to get required number of pipes:

```
#!/bin/bash

rec_egrep() {
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        exec cat
    elif [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
        exec egrep "$1"
    else
        local pat=$1
        shift
        egrep "$pat" | rec_egrep "$@"
    fi
}

first_arg="$1"
shift
grep "$first_arg" * | rec_egrep "$@"
```