# Join array in bash script with \| as separator

Tags: arrays, bash, join, ifs

I have an array with PIDs in my bash script. I would like to join these with \| as separator as to be able to use grep to search for anything that matches any of the PIDs in the array. I am basically trying to change the IFS as shown below but the problem I encounter is that instead of the desired output:

```
GREP_ARG='29126\|27435'
```

I get

```
GREP_ARG='29126\27435'.
```

This is the code I am using

```
function join {
    local IFS="$1"; shift; echo "$*";
}

GREP_ARG=$(join '\|' "${PID_ARRAY[@]}")

grep -A1 $GREP_ARG file
```

I have tried to change the input in varius ways but nothing works. Is the IFS approach to this not possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
GREP_ARG=$(printf "\|%s" "${PID_ARRAY[@]}")
GREP_ARG=${GREP_ARG:2}
```

Answer (score 1):

`IFS` in BASH supports only single character.

You can use this `join` function to get any length delimiter:

```
function join {
   d="$1"
   shift
   arr=("$@")
   last=${arr[${#arr[@]}-1]}
   unset arr[${#arr[@]}-1]
   printf -v str "%s$d" "${arr[@]}"
   printf "%s%s" "$str" "$last"
}
```

Then call it as:

```
join '\|' 29126 27435 56789; echo
29126\|27435\|56789
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function join {
    echo -n "$2"
    [[ $# -gt 2 ]] && printf "$1%s" "${@:3}"
}
```

Another version that doesn't need a subshell:

```
function join {
    VAR=$1 SEP=$2
    local __A=$3 __B
    printf -v __B "${SEP}%s" "${@:4}"
    printf -v "$VAR" '%s' "$__A$__B"
}

join GREP_ARG '\|' "${PID_ARRAY[@]}"
```

I find it that you'd do `eval` on those GREP_ARG's. Unless you really know how to safely execute those arguments with `eval`, the better way would be to use recursive piping functions, but that's already a different context from the topic. You can however refer to a [similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18125731/grep-multiple-bash-parameters).

Comment: Could do with a bit of explanation.

Comment: @TomZych Syntax functions are already explained well in the [Bash Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html). Adding more details would be quite helpful yes, but that's still optional. It would also be quite helpful to the Op if he tries to understand it by his own.