# alternative to readarray, because it does not work on mac os x

Tags: macos, perl, bash, awk

I have a varsValues.txt file

```
cat varsValues.txt
aa=13.7
something=20.6
countries=205
world=1
languages=2014
people=7.2
oceans=3.4
```

And I would like to create 2 arrays, vars and values. It should contain

```
echo ${vars[@]}
aa something countries world languages people oceans

echo ${values[@]}
13.7 20.6 205 1 2014 7.2 3.4
```

I use

```
Npars=7

readarray -t vars < <(cut -d '=' -f1 varsValues.txt)
readarray -t values < <(cut -d '=' -f2 varsValues.txt)

for (( yy=0; yy<$Npars; yy++ )); do
eval ${vars[$yy]}=${values[$yy]}
done

echo $people
7.2
```

But I would like it without readarray which does not work on Mac (os x) and IFS (interfield separater).

Any other solution? awk? perl? which I can use in my bash script.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Post some expected output. Given your input, there's an excellent chance you should just be writing an awk script, not a shell script, but we can't help you with that until we know what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the awk version. Note that `NPars` is not hardcoded.

```
vars=($(awk -F= '{print $1}' varsValues.txt))
values=($(awk -F= '{print $2}' varsValues.txt))

Npars=${#vars[@]}

for ((i=0; i<$Npars; i++)); do
    eval ${vars[$i]}=${values[$i]}
done

echo $people
```

Answer (score 19):

You could use a read loop.

```
while IFS=\= read var value; do
    vars+=($var)
    values+=($value)
done < VarsValues.txt
```

Comment: +1 This would be preferred even if `readarray` *were* available, as it avoids external processes and a second pass through the file.

Comment: In my implementation the code works without values+=($value) to create an array, where array items can be listed with ${vars[@]}.

Comment: This solution works perfectly, but pay attention to (the absence of) whitespace in `vars+=($var)`. Using `vars += ($var)` does *not* work, which surprised me a bit.

Comment: Be sure to put quotes around `"$var"` and `"$value"`, otherwise they will be split when you add them to the array if they contain spaces.

Answer (score 6):

You can use extra brackets:

```
vars=( $(cut -d '=' -f1 varsValues.txt) )
values=( $(cut -d '=' -f2 varsValues.txt) )
```

You can prefix with `declare -a` but as commenters have pointed out it's superfluous.

```
declare -a vars=( $(cut -d '=' -f1 varsValues.txt) )
declare -a values=( $(cut -d '=' -f2 varsValues.txt) )
```

Comment: It should work without the `declare`, just:  `vars=($(cut -d '=' -f1 varsValues.txt))` work fine on my Ubuntu.

Comment: That's right it should work without `declare -a` also.

Answer (score 5):

Mac uses an outdated version of bash (due to licencing reasons) by default which is lacking the readarray command.

This solution worked best for me (Mac user):

Check version of bash (probably version 3 from 2007)

```
bash --version
```

Download latest version of bash

```
brew install bash
```

Open a new terminal (which will load the new environment), then check the new version of bash (should be version 5 or higher)

```
bash --version
```

Check location(s) of bash

```
which -a bash
```

Output:

```
/usr/local/bin/bash
/bin/bash
```

You can see that you now have two versions of bash. Usually, both of these paths are in your PATH variable.

Check PATH variable

```
echo $PATH
```

The `/usr/local/bin/bash` should be standing before the `/bin/bash` in this variable. The shell is searching for executables in the order of occurrence in the PATH variable and takes the first one it finds.

Make sure to use a bash shell (rather than zsh) when using this command.

Try out the readarray command by e.g. redirecting the output of the `ls`
command with command substitution to the `readarray` command to generate an array containing a list with the filenames of the current folder:

```
readarray var < <(ls); echo ${var[@]}
```

Also, if you want to write a bash script make sure to use the correct Shebang:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
IFS=$'\n' vars=($(cut -d '=' -f1 varsValues.txt))
IFS=$'\n' values=($(cut -d '=' -f2 varsValues.txt))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -0777 -nE '@F= split /[=\r\n]/; say "@F[grep !($_%2), 0..$#F]"; say "@F[grep $_%2, 0..$#F]"' varsValues.txt
```

or by reading same file twice,

```
perl -F'=' -lane 'print $F[0]' varsValues.txt
perl -F'=' -lane 'print $F[1]' varsValues.txt
```

Comment: And then what? These doesn't populate shell variables as the sample script does.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with this:

```
$ awk -F'=' '{values[$1]=$2} END{print values["people"]}' file
7.2

$ awk -F'=' '{values[$1]=$2} END{for (name in values) print name, values[name]}' file
languages 2014
oceans 3.4
world 1
something 20.6
countries 205
people 7.2
aa 13.7
```

Now - what else do you need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Figured I'd toss this in here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AdrianTP/new-environment-setup/master/utils/readarray.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# from: https://peniwize.wordpress.com/2011/04/09/how-to-read-all-lines-of-a-file-into-a-bash-array/
readarray() {
  local __resultvar=$1
  declare -a __local_array
  let i=0
  while IFS=$'\n' read -r line_data; do
      __local_array[i]=${line_data}
      ((++i))
  done < $2
  if [[ "$__resultvar" ]]; then
    eval $__resultvar="'${__local_array[@]}'"
  else
    echo "${__local_array[@]}"
  fi
}
```

I keep this in a "utils" folder in my "new-environment-setup" Github repo, and I just clone it down and import it whenever I need to read a file into an array of lines an array get a new computer or wipe my drive. It should thus act as a backfill for readarray's shortcomings on Mac.

Import looks like:

```sh
# From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12694189/771948
DIR="${BASH_SOURCE%/*}"
if [[ ! -d "$DIR" ]]; then DIR="$PWD"; fi
. "$DIR/utils/readarray.sh"
```

Usage looks like `readarray "<output_var_name>" "<input_file_name>"`.

Yes it's a little rough. Sorry about that. It may not even work correctly anymore, but it did at one point, so I thought I would share it here to plant the idea of simply...writing your own backfill.