# Assigning space-separated computed values to array in bash is inconsistent with printing

Tags: arrays, bash, text

I had the following piece of az cli output in plain text:

```
echo $raw_containers_string
[
  {
    "name": "123"
  },
  {
    "name": "vbm-container"
  }
]
```

After some text refinement, I have a string returned containing this (zsh):

```
echo $raw_containers_string | grep name | cut -d ":" -f2 | tr '\n' " "
"123"  "vbm-container" %
```

(It also has a % symbol at the end, but that's [expected](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302661/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-appeared-at-the-end-of-unix-command-output))

I now need to create an array of these 2 strings (123 and vbm-container) to iterate through it.

1. `declare -a arr=($(echo $raw_containers_string | grep name | cut -d ":" -f2 | tr '\n' " "))`

   - returns `"123"  "vb -co t i r"`
2. `arr=($(echo $raw_containers_string | grep name | cut -d ":" -f2 | tr '\n' " "))`

   - returns `"123"  "vb -co t i r"`

These are indices of an array (if it matters):

```
➜  bash-az-list-blobs git:(master) ✗ echo $myvar[0]

➜  bash-az-list-blobs git:(master) ✗ echo $myvar[1]
 "123"  "vb
➜  bash-az-list-blobs git:(master) ✗ echo $myvar[2]
-co
➜  bash-az-list-blobs git:(master) ✗ echo $myvar[3]
t
➜  bash-az-list-blobs git:(master) ✗ echo $myvar[4]
i
➜  bash-az-list-blobs git:(master) ✗ echo $myvar[5]

➜  bash-az-list-blobs git:(master) ✗ echo $myvar[6]
r"
```

**Questions**

1. I want to understand why the behaviour between printing it to the
   terminal and assigning it to a variable is different.
2. I would also
   like to know how I assign my refined to an array in zsh, so that `echo arr` returns a 2-elements iterable array.

**UPD (08-16)**

Using `jq` does filter JSON successfully

```
echo "$raw_containers_string" | jq -r '.[].name'
123
vbm-container
```

The problem is to pack these values into an array (this was exactly the purpose of this thread):

```
declare -a arr=$(echo "$raw_containers_string" | jq -r '.[].name')
echo $arr
123 vbm-container
echo $arr[0]
123 vbm-container[0]
echo $arr[1]
123 vbm-container[1]
```

Why accessing the first element of my array just add index "[0]" to an output?

```
echo "$raw_containers_string" | jq -r '.[].name'
→ 123
vbm-container

declare -a containers_array=($(echo "$raw_containers_string" | jq -r '.[].name|@sh' | tr '\n' " "))
→ "123"

eval "containers_array=($(echo "$raw_containers_string" | jq -r '.[].name|@sh'))"
→ 123

eval "containers_array=($(echo "$raw_containers_string" | jq '.[].name|@sh'))"
→ '123'

echo $IFS
→
```

Comment: Why is this tagged bash if you're using zsh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `jq`:

```
eval "names=($(echo "$raw_containers_string" |
               jq -r '.[].name|@sh'))"
```

Now you have a shell array `names`, where each name is an element. Piping to `@sh` means each value is quoted as a separate shell word, safe to `eval`.

Comment: It doesn't work.`echo $raw_containers_string` - `[ { "name": "123" }, { "name": "vbm-container" } ]`. I then run your command and my `names` is this `123`. I expect both items to be in it, not only first one

Comment: @feedthemachine Read arrays section of `man bash`. `printf '%s\n' "${names[@]}"` or `echo "${names[0]}"; echo "${names[1]}"`. Both names are in the shell array.

Comment: Thanks, that was the easiest way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You're counting on word-splitting of unquoted variable/command substitutions to separate the elements of the array, and have apparently also changed `IFS`. These are both bad ideas, and together they're a recipe for chaos. You're also using zsh for interactive testing, and it does word splitting very differently from bash, so you'll get *different* weird results from it.

First, track down what's changing `IFS` and fix it. You appear to have it set to something really weird, containing at least "m", "n", "a", and "e", so it's probably set by mistake.

If it actually does need to be changed, you need to keep it from *staying* changed. You can either make the change local to a specific command by making it a prefix of the command (e.g. `IFS=',' read field1 field2`) or by resetting it after using the changed value (e.g. `saveIFS="$IFS"; IFS=","; doSomethingWithIFS; IFS="$saveIFS"), or just find a different way to solve whatever you changed` IFS` for in the first place.

Second, get in the habit of [double-quoting variable and command substitutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55023461/when-should-i-double-quote-a-parameter-expansion). There are some specific situations where you shouldn't double-quote them, and some situations where it's optional, but it's safest to just assume it should be double-quoted in most cases. [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at pointing out quoting problems (and many other common mistakes).

Instead of using word-splitting on an unquoted substitution to populate the array, use `readarray -t` to read each line of input into a separate array element (or `read -ra` to read *words* into elements -- but fix `IFS` first, or it'll also split weirdly). Note that you can't put these in a pipeline, or they execute in a subshell and the value gets lost; instead, use process substitution: `readarray -t < <(somecommand)`

Third, that `grep | cut` thing is going to output something with extra spaces and quotes around the actual values. Anyway, when parsing JSON, it's better to use a tool like `jq` that actually speaks the language.

So, with all that fixed, try this:

```
readarray -t arr < <(echo "$raw_containers_string" | jq -r '.[].name')
```

Léa Gris pointed out that you can simplify this even further by passing the string to `jq` with `--argjson` instead of `echo` and a pipe:

```
readarray -t arr < <(jq -rn --argjson j "$raw_containers_string" '$j[].name')
```

If you have an older version of bash that doesn't support `readarray` (i.e. you're on macOS), you can fake it with `read` and some delimiter switching:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -a arr < <(jq -rn --argjson j "$raw_containers_string" '$j[].name')
```

Here, the `-d ''` part makes it treat the entire thing as one big line, and `IFS=$'\n'` tells it to break that "line" into fields on newline delimiters. Since the `IFS` assignment is a prefix to the `read` command, it only applies to that one command and won't cause trouble later. One warning, though: technically, the `read` command will exit with an error status (because it never saw an end-of-line delimiter), so if you use `set -e` or `shopt -s errexit` it'll make the script exit (add `|| true` at the end to prevent this).

(And if you need to check the contents of an array -- or even a plain variable -- `declare -p arr` is more reliable than `echo`.)

Comment: Save an `echo` and a sub-shell pipe: `readarray -t arr < <(jq -rn --argjson j "$raw_containers_string" '$j[].name')`

Comment: @LéaGris Nice. I've edited it in...

Comment: It is not a full replacement for piping-in the JSON as a stream. because of argument length limitations, the JSON argument might not fit. That said, you usually get the JSON as a result of some command and spending a sub-shell to collect the JSON string, then another sub-shell to stream it to `jq` is kind of wasteful. Stream pipe the output of the command providing the JSON directly to `jq` and let the system deal with cashing (what it does better than reinventing the cache within a shell.

Comment: `readarray` doesn't work on macOS. Alternative suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842261/alternative-to-readarray-because-it-does-not-work-on-mac-os-x) is not helpful either, it gives me
`bash: $raw_containers_string: ambiguous redirect`

Comment: @feedthemachine I added a way to make it work with older versions of bash.