# Linux bash know the script path which includes library script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a library script named A and a script B, C which includes A with

```
. ../../../A
```

The problem is how A can know which time I run `./B.sh` or `./C.sh`, example:

```
if(run ./B.sh)
   echo "B (file path) is calling"
else
   echo "C (file path) is calling"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$0` to determine the command that was executed:

A.sh:

```
echo $0
```

B.sh:

```
. ./A.sh
```

When run:

```
$ sh B.sh 
B.sh
$ sh A.sh 
A.sh
```

It will only give the command that was executed, not the arguments:

```
$ sh B.sh one two three
B.sh
```

Comment: Thanks, it is the easiest way.

Comment: Be aware that using `. ../../../A` will only work relative to your current working directory. If you execute `B.sh` from another location the `source` built-in will fail. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/192305/341459 for a better way.