# How run a shell script from another shell script

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu-14.04

I have recently install tomcat8 on Ubuntu. It is located at /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.36/bin and need to run ./shutdown.sh and ./startup.sh manually. Can anybody suggest me a shell scrip that can do startup, shutdown and even restart servers ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192292/bash-how-best-to-include-other-scripts

Answer (score 2):

this can help you

```
#!/bin/bash
start() {
/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.36/bin/startup.sh  
}

stop() {
/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.36/bin/shutdown.sh 
}

case "$1" in 
    start)
       start
       ;;
    stop)
       stop
       ;;
    restart)
       stop
       start
       ;;
    *)
       echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
esac

exit 0
```