# Why does not working bash files include?

Tags: bash, shell

I looked now more like a theme (e.g.: [Bash: How _best_ to include other scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192292/bash-how-best-to-include-other-scripts), it also tried none of them work.

I should also call "**create_sample_html.sh**" file in the same directory in the "**test.sh**" file.

But no matter what I tried, nothing happens when you run.

But in I tried to run script in Docker container return the following error message:

> ./create_sample_html.sh: No such file or directory
>
> create_php_info: command not found
>
> create_html: command not found

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

source ./create_sample_html.sh

IP=$(ip route get 1 | awk '{print $NF;exit}')

create_php_info "<path-to-file>/index.php"
create_html ${IP} "test1" "<path-to-file>/index.html"

exit 0
```

create_sample_html.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
create_html() {
    touch $3
    echo -e "<!Doctype html>" >> $3
    echo -e "<html>" >> $3
    echo -e "\t<head>" >> $3
    echo -e "\t\t<meta charset=\"utf-8\">" >> $3
    echo -e "\t\t<title>Server $1 VHost: $2</title>" >> $3
    echo -e "\t</head>" >> $3
    echo -e "  " >> $3
    echo -e "\t<body>" >> $3
    echo -e "\t\t<h1>Server $1 VHost: $2</h1>" >> $3
    echo -e "\t</body>" >> $3
    echo -e "</html>" >> $3
}

create_php_info() {
    touch $1
    echo -e "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" >> $1
}
exit 0
```

file permissions:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user  480 aug    3 20:48 create_sample_html.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user  332 aug    3 20:37 test.sh
```

Comment: show how you invoke `test.sh` command. Another option to consider is giving absolute path for `create_sample_html.sh`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `create_sample_html.sh`, remove `exit 0`.

Else, `test.sh` will execute `exit 0` at the moment you are sourcing it. In the same step you can also remove `#!/bin/bash` from the sourced file because it's unnecessary since the functions will be executed with the shell of the parent script anyway.