# Can the jshell command `/open` work relatively to the folder containing the script, instead of the working directory?

Tags: java, java-9, jshell

I have two jshell scripts *script.jsh* and *commons.jsh* in the same folder `/path/folder`.

**script.jsh**:

```
/open commons.jsh
```

**commons.jsh**:

```
System.out.println("commons.jsh loaded")
```

- If I am in `/path/folder`, I can run `jshell script.jsh` and it works well
- If I am in `/path/folder/subfolder` and I run `jshell ../script.jsh`, it fails with `File 'commons.jsh' for '/open' is not found`.

Is there any solution to this? In other words, can the jshell command `/open` work relatively to the folder containing the script, instead of the working directory?

A similar question was asked here for bash: [Bash: How _best_ to include other scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192292/bash-how-best-to-include-other-scripts)

***Edit1***: making the question more precise

***Edit2***: here are the real jshell scripts that I was working on when writing this question, the first script available here https://framagit.org/Gwendal/helpful-scripts/blob/3e8118970a6a412dfe0f199e93545745d890243f/jshell/dia2pdf.jsh which opens this second script containing a helper method https://framagit.org/Gwendal/helpful-scripts/blob/3e8118970a6a412dfe0f199e93545745d890243f/jshell/commons.jsh

Comment: Well thought over this one for a while and restricting it to this comment. IMHO, the use case boils down to the need of Interactive Shell[(!=REPL)](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2012/06/26/shell-repl/). A prime difference of using the specific location of an X script to be executed from Y location. Not to deny the fact that such user inputs can be supported, but needs to be evaluated for a [REPL to provide that](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/168285/difference-between-a-repl-and-interactive-shell). Though, what might work is wrapping the `.jsh` with a `.sh` script eq.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i've been looking into this one for quite some time...

And the only way i know of is to just add the **full path** of the *"commons.jsh"*-file.
And it works.

Comment: Not quite, a full path isn't relative, but at least this answers the question.