# New to bash scripting - want to have a code block execute many times via reference

Tags: linux, bash, shell, posix

I am totally new to bash scripting.  I am wondering if there's a way that I can create a reference for the following code block:

```
read -t5 -n1 -r -p 'Press any key or wait five seconds...' key
if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
    echo 'A key was pressed.'
else
    echo 'Five seconds passed. Continuing...'
fi
```

Is there a way I can give this block of code a reference point and execute it using the reference several times throughout the rest of the script?

Would it be easier/better to create a separate script using this particular code and then reference it in the rest of the script I'm writing using include?  e.g.  [Bash: How _best_ to include other scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192292/bash-how-best-to-include-other-scripts)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for a function?  `foo() { cmds; }`

Comment: Also, you can simplify exit status testing (note that `[` is actually a command and `if` tests its exit code): `if read -t5 ...; then echo Key pressed; else echo Timeout; fi`.

Comment: Tangentially, note that the very purpose of `if` is to run a command and examine its exit code. In other words, `cmd; if [ "$?" = "0" ]; then ...` is more idiomatically and elegantly written `if cmd; then ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do that: Make it a function.

```
ReadKey() {
    read -t5 -n1 -r -p 'Press any key or wait five seconds...' key
    if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
        echo 'A key was pressed.'
    else
        echo 'Five seconds passed. Continuing...'
    fi
}
```

And then call it:

```
ReadKey
```

Comment: Sweet, that looks great.  I will try it!  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, wasn't apparent to me where to click at first.  Thanks :)