# How to get script file path inside script itself when called through sym link

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

When I need to get path to the script file inside script itself I use something like this:

```
`dirname $0`
```

that works file until I call the script through sym link to it. In that case above code prints the location of the link instead the original file.

Is there a way to get the path of the original script file, not the link?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Ok. I have found the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665/how-to-resolve-symlinks-in-a-shell-script

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
if [ -L $0 ] ; then
    DIR=$(dirname $(readlink -f $0)) ;
else
    DIR=$(dirname $0) ;
fi ;
```

Comment: In case when readlink is not available the answer is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665/how-to-resolve-symlinks-in-a-shell-script

Comment: Curious why do you need to run different commands when `$0` is a symlink or not? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/432475/apply-readlink-to-a-non-symlink-file

Comment: Why not just use `$(dirname $(readlink -f $0))`` regardless of whether $0` contains symlink or not?

Answer (score 17):

You **really** need to read the following BashFAQ article:

- [BashFAQ/028 - How do I determine the location of my script? I want to read some config files from the same place.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028)

The truth is, the `$0` hacks are NOT reliable, and they will fail whenever applications are started with a zeroth argument that is not the application's path.  For example, `login(1)` will put a `-` in front of your application name in `$0`, causing breakage, and whenever you invoke an application that's in `PATH` `$0` won't contain the path to your application but just the filename, which means you can't extract any location information out of it.  There are a LOT more ways in which this can fail.

Bottom line: Don't rely on the hack, the truth is you **cannot** figure out where your script is, so use a configuration option to set the directory of your config files or whatever you need the script's path for.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I will check out the FAQ.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`readlink`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?readlink) for that:

```
readlink -f "$0"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dir=$(dirname $(readlink -f "$0"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this one:

```
dirname $(realpath $0)
```

example:

```
skaerst@test01-centos7:~/Documents> ../test/path.sh 
dirname realpath: /home/skaerst/test

skaerst@test01-centos7:~/Documents> cat ../test/path.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "dirname realpath: $(dirname $(realpath $0))"
```

works with symlinks too because realpath uses -P by default:

```
skaerst@test01-centos7:~/Documents> ln -s ../test/path.sh p
skaerst@test01-centos7:~/Documents> ./p
dirname realpath: /home/skaerst/test
```

realpath is available with coreutils >8.5, I guess

```
skaerst@test01-centos7:~/Documents> rpm -qf $(which realpath) $(which dirname)
coreutils-8.22-15.el7_2.1.x86_64
coreutils-8.22-15.el7_2.1.x86_64
```

hth

Regards

Stefan