# How to resolve a symbolic link to a parent directory in a shell script?

Tags: shell, proguard, symlink, dirname

The following line introduces the local variable `PROGUARD_HOME` within a [shell script](http://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/code/ci/proguard4.10/tree/bin/proguard.sh):

```
PROGUARD_HOME=`dirname "$0"`/..
```

This points to the parent folder of the shell script. The script executes normally. - Then, I created the symlink `/usr/local/bin/proguard` which refers to `~/bin/proguard4.10/bin/proguard.sh`. When I run proguard using the symlink `PROGUARD_HOME` is no longer resolved correctly. This causes the following error message output by the shell script:

> Error: Unable to access jarfile /usr/local/bin/../lib/proguard.jar

How can I rewrite the allocation of the enviroment variable so that it resolves an symbolic link if present?
I am aware of a very similar question on [resolving symbolic links in shell scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665/how-to-resolve-symbolic-links-in-a-shell-script) but still cannot figure out how to combine those solutions with the parent folder approach here.

Comment: What actually prints the Error: Unable to...?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a Bash script tell what directory it's stored in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a `readlink -f $0` to reveal the target of the shell script itself, then a `dirname` to strip off the script, then another `readlink -f` on the product of that should do the trick:

```
PROGUARD_HOME=$(readlink -f $(dirname $(readlink -f "$0"))/..)
```

A more step-by-step breakdown:

```
echo "\$0 is $0"
TRUENAMEOFSCRIPT=$(readlink -f $0)
echo "readlink -f of \$0 reveals $TRUENAMEOFSCRIPT"

DIRNAMEOFSCRIPT=$(dirname $TRUENAMEOFSCRIPT)
echo "The script lives in directory $DIRNAMEOFSCRIPT"

PARENTDIR=$(readlink -f "$DIRNAMEOFSCRIPT"/..)
echo "Its parent dir is $PARENTDIR"
```