# Bash: how to get real path of a symlink?

Tags: bash, symlink

Is it possible, executing a file symlinked in `/usr/local/bin` folder, to get the absolute path of original script? Well, .. I know where original file is, and I know it because I am linkging it. But, ... I want this script working, even if I move original source code (and symlink).

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "my path is ..."
```

Comment: readlink is a function I can call in a bash script? I am trying but is not working =(

Comment: readlink is a binary which is part of coreutils

Comment: `readlink -f filename`  gives you a full path to link target.

Comment: @PavelPatrin Only for GNU `readlink`, not for BSD.

Comment: coreutils isn't installed by default on every system that includes bash.  `stat` is more consistently available, but it too has different usage depending on your operating system.

Comment: Many tools exist for this.  Just a few I have installed from Debian are `realpath`, `chase` and `readlink`.  No doubt other platforms have a wide choice, too.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`readlink` is not a standard command, but it's common on Linux and BSD, including OS X, and it's the most straightforward answer to your question. BSD and GNU readlink implementations are different, so read the documentation for the one you have.

If `readlink` is not available, or you need to write a cross-platform script that isn't bound to a specific implementation:

If the symlink is also a directory, then

```
cd -P "$symlinkdir"
```

will get you into the dereferenced directory, so

```
echo "I am in $(cd -P "$symlinkdir" && pwd)"
```

will echo the fully dereferenced directory. That said, `cd -P` dereferences the entire path, so if you have more than one symlink in the same path you can have unexpected results.

If the symlink is to a file, not a directory, you may not need to dereference the link. Most commands follow symlinks harmlessly. If you simply want to check if a file is a link, use `test -L`.

Comment: My "#!/bin/bash" script, doing the command: echo "I am in $(cd -P "$symlinkdir" && pwd)", print "/usr/local/bin/ttmux: line 4: cd: : No such file or directory"

Comment: `pwd` has also the `-P` option. If you already are in the directory you can do : `pwd -P`. Also if you are not in : `(cd /path/w/symlinks/ && pwd -P)`

Comment: after `pwd -P` , is there a way to do  `cd ..`  (without using copy and paste) ?

Comment: What about `cd -`, @TaiwanGrapefruitTea ?

Besides @Boop 's code is in parantheses and executes in a subshell, so it does not actually change current directory of the current shell.

Answer (score 38):

lets assume we have real script or file and symbolic link to it:

```
$ ls -la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root    root  0 Mar 20 07:05 realscript.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root    root 10 Mar 20 07:05 symlink -> realscript.sh
```

And the part of GNU coreutils are few very useful commands:

```
$ realpath symlink
/home/test/realscript.sh
```

see also on original:

```
realpath realscript.sh
/home/test/realscript.sh
```

Also very good combination in scripting is to use `dirname` on script

```
$ dirname /home/test/realscript.sh
/home/test
```

so to wrap it up, you can use in script

```
echo  $( dirname $(realpath "symlink") )
```

or to get and store in variable real script home dir and save code to get real path script realscript.sh:

```
script_home=$( dirname $(realpath "$0") )
echo Original script home: $script_home
```

Where "$0" is defined as "self" in shell script.

To test everything, we put symlink into /home/test2/, amend some additional things and run/call it from root directory:

```
$ /home/test2/symlink
/home/test
Original script home: /home/test
Original script is: /home/test/realscript.sh
Called script is: /home/test2/symlink
```

Please try to write your self the amended outputs :)

Update 2021, there is also command:

readlink - print resolved symbolic links or canonical file names

DESCRIPTION
Note realpath(1) is the preferred command to use for canonicalization functionality.

Answer (score 8):

If you are working on GNU/Linux, you can use readlink: `readlink -f $LINK`
On macOS you can also use the greadlink command: `greadlink -f $LINK`