# truncate a string in bash with variable expansion formatting

Tags: bash

I am trying to truncate a string in bash, specifically to get into the directory of an executable linked by a symlink. For example:

```
[alva@brnzn ~ $] ls -algh $(which python3.4)
lrwxr-xr-x  1 admin    73B 26 May 02:49 /opt/local/bin/python3.4 -> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4
```

So i cut out the fields I don't need:

```
[alva@brnzn ~ $] ls -algh $(which python3.4) | cut -d" " -f 14
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4
```

I need help to cut out everything after the last `/`. I am interested in a solution were I can save the previous string in a var and using variable expansion to cut out the part of the string I dont need. e.g. `printf '%s\n' "${path_str#*/}"` (this is just an example).

Thank you!

Comment: Why can't you save the previous string in a variable? `path_str=$(command)` saves the output of a command in a variable.

Comment: Indeed I would do so, but the point of the question is not how to save a string in a variable, but how to truncate part of it. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, it looked like you already knew how to use expansion operators to truncate part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this be what you need?

```
$ x=/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4
$ echo ${x%/*}
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for. May you point me to the documentation of the syntax you have used?

Comment: @alva It's documented in the bash manual, in the section on parameter expansion.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dirname` to retrieve the final directory-name and than assign it to a variable, so the solution could be:

```
MY_VAR=$( dirname $(ls -algh $(which python3.4) | cut -d" " -f 14) )
```

But I prefer to use `readlink` to show the linked file so your code should be:

```
MY_VAR=$( dirname $( readlink $(which python3.4) )
```

Take a look to [How to resolve symbolic links in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665/how-to-resolve-symbolic-links-in-a-shell-script) to read the full history.